# The current request is ambiguous MVC Attribute Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

Have 3 Attribute Routes

`[Route("{foo}_{bar}_{fee}_o_p")]`
`ActionResult SelectFee`
`[Route("{foo}_{bar}_{fee}_{fii}_o_p")]` `ActionResult SelectFii`
`[Route("{foo}_{bar}_{fee}_{fii}_{fum}_o_p")]` `ActionResult SelectFum`

The First 2 work as expected.
But the last one comes  up with an ambiguous Reflection Error.

It is also strange if I was to move the 2 of them out to another area/controller the ambiguous error comes up for them as well
If I update to 
`[Route("Select/{foo}_{bar}_{fee}_{fii}_{fum}_o_p")]` `ActionResult SelectFum`
It Works...

Routes are 
`public ActionResult SelectFee(string foo, string bar, string fee)` 
 
`public ActionResult SelectFii(string foo, string bar, string fee, string fii)` 
`public ActionResult SelectFum(string foo, string bar, string fee, string fii, string fum)`

The Exact Error from Elmah
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: The current request is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SelectedFee(System.String, System.String, System.String) on type RexProject.Controllers.ShopController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SelectFii(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String) on type RexProject.Controllers.ShopController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SelectFum(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String) on type RexProject.Controllers.ShopController

Any input would be helpful!
Thanks!

Solution(Or work around)
Removed the Attribute routing, and placed them inside of RegisterRoutes Method of the RouteConfig, Longest First, and they are working as expected.

Comment: All 3 routes are identical - they specify that the url contains one segment only.

Comment: show your full action signature. If last parameter is nullable than it's the reason you get that error

Answer (score 0):

The custom routing should not be needed if this is a standard get, the binding will be done automatically from the querystring, it seems like you're just trying to change the url format and i'm not sure what you gain from it.

```
public ActionResult SelectFum(string foo = null, string bar = null, string fee = null, string fii = null, string fum = null) 
{
   //your code
}
```

Comment: But that does nothing for SEO